# NullPointerException in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

having some problem with my school work, and hope i can get some help here! Apparently there's a nullpointerexception error at line 17.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Librarian {
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public Librarian() {
        bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }
    public ArrayList<Book> findBooksWrittenBy(ArrayList<Book> bookList, String author) {
        ArrayList<Book> booksByAuthor = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
            Book book = bookList.get(i);
            String author1 = book.getAuthor();
            if(author1.equalsIgnoreCase(author)) {
                booksByAuthor.add(book);
            }
            if(booksByAuthor.size() != 0) {
                booksByAuthor = booksByAuthor;
            }else {
                booksByAuthor = null;
            }
        }
        return booksByAuthor;
    }
```

Comment: can you indicate what is line 17 is it this if(booksByAuthor.size() != 0) {  ?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: yeap it's if(booksByAuthor.size() != 0) {

Comment: You have several problems, but in order to figure them out we need to see the code that invokes `findBooksWrittenBy`.  You may be confusing the member variable `Librarian.bookList` with the parameter `bookList`.  The way it's written now, `findBooksWrittenBy` searches the passed-in list, not the Librarian member List.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line: - `booksByAuthor = booksByAuthor;`

Comment: It seems like this statement will inevitably cause a NullPointerException:  `booksByAuthor = null;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place your check on authors outside of the for loop.
Then, check for size and return immediately, it is redundant to assign an object to itself.

As follows:

```
  public ArrayList<Book> findBooksWrittenBy(ArrayList<Book> bookList, String author) {
    ArrayList<Book> booksByAuthor = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
        Book book = bookList.get(i);
        String author1 = book.getAuthor();
        if(author1.equalsIgnoreCase(author)) {
            booksByAuthor.add(book);
        }
    }
    if(booksByAuthor.size() > 0) {
        return booksByAuthor;
    }else {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only answer that makes sense. 1+

Answer (score 3):

Shorter and better:

```
public List<Book> findBooksWrittenBy(ArrayList<Book> bookList, String author) {
    List<Book> booksByAuthor = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(Book b: bookList) {
        if(author.equalsIgnoreCase(b.getAuthor) {
            booksByAuthor.add(book);
        }
    }
    return booksByAuthor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems your first iteration is working fine and it will add data to booksByAuthor object in second iteration it is not zero and hence it set to null as it in your code.

suggest :

```
public ArrayList<Book> findBooksWrittenBy(ArrayList<Book> bookList, String author) {
    ArrayList<Book> booksByAuthor = new ArrayList<Book>();
    for(int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
        Book book = bookList.get(i);
        String author1 = book.getAuthor();
        if(author1.equalsIgnoreCase(author)) {
            booksByAuthor.add(book);
        }

    }
    return booksByAuthor;
}
```

Comment: check the suggested way is fine with you

Comment: 1+. Agree that it likely is better to return an empty ArrayList than a null one.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably when i=0, there is no match between bookList(0).getAuthor() and the author parameter, which doesn't add any book in your booksByAuthor list. So the else statement will be executed and results in the booksByAuthor is set to null.

Then when i=1, you called a method on a null object which caused NPE.